# Mongoose passing class functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I pass functions to mongoose, it seems it no longer has a reference to `this`. Is there a better way to go about this? All functions are simplified for length reasons. I cannot edit the function `getUsernameForId` to take additional parameters.

I have class:

```
var class = new function() {

    this.func1 = function(data) {
        return data + "test";
    }

    this.func2 = function(data) {
        var next = function(username) {
            return this.func1(username); // THIS THROWS undefined is not a function
        }
        mongoose.getUsernameForId(1, func3);
    }

}
```

mongoose is another class like this:

```
var getUsernameForId = function(id, callback) {
    user_model.findOne({"id": id}, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        callback(user.username);
    });
}
```

How do I resolve the `undefined is not a function error`. I do not want to duplicate code because func1 is pretty long in reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your code how `next` is used, but if you need it to be invoked with correct `this` you can try to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
this.func2 = function(data) {

    var next = function(username) {
        return this.func1(username);
    }.bind(this);

    mongoose.getUsernameForId(1, func3);
}
```

I assume that you simplified code for the post and `next` does more things in reality. But if it indeed just returns result of `this.func1` then you could shorten it:

```
var next = this.func1.bind(this);
```

Comment: New to JS and was not aware of this function. Accept in a min. Is this a commonly used convention?

Comment: Yes, bind is pretty convenient and common these days, and allows nice syntax.